# How to convert a file into a rasterized object in Illustrator using scripting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to do this for a batch of files, so I need help on converting a file into a rasterized object, and then using a gaussian blur on it afterwards, in the built-in JavaScript.

I so far have not found any easy way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you ought to use the automaton. Here is a quick tutorial on how to create new Actions. Post back if you need more help.

http://vectips.com/tricks/automate-actions-in-illustrator/